# RegEx: Don't match a certain character if it's inside quotes

Tags: regex, escaping, quotes

Disclosure: I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) many times here on SO and I know better than to use regex to parse HTML. This question is just to broaden my knowledge with regex.

Say I have this string:

```
some text <tag link="fo>o"> other text
```

I want to match the whole tag but if I use `<[^>]+>` it only matches `<tag link="fo>`.

How can I make sure that `>` inside of quotes can be ignored.

I can trivially write a parser with a while loop to do this, but I want to know how to do it with regex.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Regular Expression:

```
<[^>]*?(?:(?:('|")[^'"]*?\1)[^>]*?)*>
```

#### Online demo:

[http://regex101.com/r/yX5xS8](http://regex101.com/r/yX5xS8/1)

#### Full Explanation:

I know this regex might be a headache to look at, so here is my explanation:

```
<                      # Open HTML tags
    [^>]*?             # Lazy Negated character class for closing HTML tag
    (?:                # Open Outside Non-Capture group
        (?:            # Open Inside Non-Capture group
            ('|")      # Capture group for quotes, backreference group 1
            [^'"]*?    # Lazy Negated character class for quotes
            \1         # Backreference 1
        )              # Close Inside Non-Capture group
        [^>]*?         # Lazy Negated character class for closing HTML tag
    )*                 # Close Outside Non-Capture group
>                      # Close HTML tags
```

Comment: Are you sure `[^\1]` does what you think it does? I don't think `\1` can be used inside a character class like that.

Comment: You are correct! How silly of me. I changed it so that it is a negated character class for quotes, since that is all we will ever match with group 1 anyway. Although this introduces problems when we begin to have single quotes inside double quotes... I do have a solution for that, but it's very long.

Comment: Amazingly gorgeous and beautiful piece of regex! Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply have to regexes? One for `"` delimited args, and one for `'`? Then try the second regex only if the second did not match?

Comment: or, for that matter you could use `(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")` (instead of `(?:('|")[^'"]*?\1)`). (You really don't need the `*?` qualifier inside the quotes. The match will always be the same here regardless of whether you use `*` or `*?`.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight improvement on Vasili Syrakis answer. It handles `"…"` and `'…'` completely separately, and does not use the `*?` qualifier.

### Regular expression

`<[^'">]*(("[^"]*"|'[^']*')[^'">]*)*>`

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/jO1oQ1

#### Explanation

```
<                    # start of HTML tag
    [^'">]*          #   any non-single, non-double quote or greater than
    (                #   outer group
        (            #     inner group
            "[^"]*"  #       "..."
        |            #      or
            '[^']*'  #       '...'
        )            #
        [^'">]*      #   any non-single, non-double quote or greater than
    )*               #   zero or more of outer group
>                    # end of HTML tag
```

This version is *slightly* better than Vasilis's in that single quotes are allowed inside `"…"`, and double quotes are allowed inside `'…'`, and that a (incorrect) tag like `<a href='>` will *not* be matched.

It is slightly *worse* than Vasili's solution in that the groups are captured. If you do not want that, replace `(` with `(?:`, in all places. (Just using `(` makes the regex shorter, and a little bit more readable).

Answer (score 0):

```
(<.+?>[^<]+>)|(<.+?>)
```

you can make two regexs than put them togather by using '|',
in this case :

```
(<.+?>[^<]+>)   #will match  some text <tag link="fo>o"> other text
(<.+?>)         #will match  some text <tag link="foo"> other text
```

if the first case match, it will not use second regex, so make sure you put special case in the firstplace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work with escaped double quotes, try:

`/>(?=((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"([^"\\]|\\.)*")*([^"\\]|\\.)*$)/g`

For example:

```
const gtExp = />(?=((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"([^"\\]|\\.)*")*([^"\\]|\\.)*$)/g;
const nextGtMatch = () => ((exec) => {
    return exec ? exec.index : -1;
})(gtExp.exec(xml));
```

And if you're parsing through a bunch of XML, you'll want to set `.lastIndex`.

```
gtExp.lastIndex = xmlIndex;
const attrEndIndex = nextGtMatch(); // the end of the tag's attributes
```